# Как создать переменную для хранения не корректных символов?

Tags: python

Пробовал вот это, но не знаю как обозначит символы в переменной uncorrectsymbols, чтобы цикл смог прочитать их отдельно и если один из них существует в строке email.get(), то выдавал окно с предупреждением

```
if uncorrectsymbols in email.get()
  showinfo(title='Registration', message="Uncorrect symbols !")
```

Comment: `if any(x in email.get() for x in uncorrectsymbols):`

Comment: thank you so much